# Where can I find completed production items connected to Order

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, x++

I'm tring to create a report that contains produced items in a certail timeline. 
How or where can I find completed items. My prodtable contains mostly half products.
It should look like: Order reference - Date -  Ordered items - produced items

Comment: Completed in what sense? By the status of the production or by reported finished count. Does partially finished productions count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "Reference level" equal zero.

```
while select prodTable where prodTable.CollectRefLevel == 0 
{ ... }
```